# Error when uploading multiple files in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, error, file-upload

My customer is unable to upload multiple files to a document library in SharePoint 2010 Server.

Here’s how they produce the error: 
1. They go to the document library, hit the "Documents" tab and the "Upload document" button. 
2. On the new dialog, they hit the link "Upload multiple files..."
3. They select 3 files in the explorer window and click OK.
4. The upload fails, displaying the error message: http://images.devs-on.net/Image/K0ZV2vLpAdTfYJXE-Region.png ("cannot run microsoft sharepoint foundation on the page"… upload.aspx)

They have the following environment: Server: SharePoint 2010 Server on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.
Workstations: Windows XP MS Office 2007

Now, here’s the interesting thing: I don’t get the error when uploading files to their SharePoint server via my laptop with Windows 7 and MS Office 2010. Also, my upload windows looks different from theirs, offering drag-and-drop functionality.

Hours of Google troubleshooting has produced the following fruitless leads:

- Due to insufficient permissions:
  http://www.sharepoint-guru.com/2011/05/problem-with-uploading-multiple.html
  This doesn’t seem to be the case as it is happening to their super
  user with “Full control” permissions on the web site.
- Due to a corrupt Upload.aspx:
  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/2a481af5-ce41-41b0-b352-070a9ac73f11
  This doesn’t seem to be the case either – their Upload.aspx already looks correct.

So, what could it be then? I'm clean out of ideas so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your second link is garbled, there should be a space before "This".

Comment: I have the same problem, don't get any error message. It happens when I drag and drop *or* try to upload several, whether several is 40, 7 or 2. I know I have permissions, as my single uploads work just fine.
And (as per the second suggestion) my Upload.aspx also looks fine. Any ideas? Do I need an active X plugin or something?

Answer (score 2):

Even Though this is very old Thread Still somebody may need a clear cut answers.

I experienced the same in my Dev Box...

When you upload the file and You don't get any http 400,401..etc errors, if only you got upload status failed then there is everything you need to fix in your client machine.

I faced the same problem with Windows 7 and MS Office 2010, After spending more than half a day and reviewed plenty of forums related to it

But this one was an eye opener for me, Thinks that i was did,

1. I uninstalled my MS office 2010
2. Installed MS office 2007 and Set IE in 32-bit mode
3. Reboot system and now it works fine..

Please refer the following link for more info,

http://qazimobeen.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/sharepoint-multiple-files-upload-feature/

Just Refer this,

1) Windows XP and Office 2007
a. Upload multiple documents will work regardless of the order you install .NET (up to 3.5) and Office 2007
b. Upload multiple documents will NOT work without Office 2007 installed
c. Upload multiple documents WILL work even WITHOUT .NET installed, and only Office 2007 installed

2) Windows XP and Office 2010
a. Upload multiple documents will work ONLY if you install .NET up to version 3.5 BEFORE you install Office 2010
b. Upload multiple documents will NOT work without Office 2010 installed
c. Upload multiple documents will NOT work without .NET up to 3.5 (SP1) installed

3) Windows 7 and Office 2007
a. Upload multiple documents will always work in this situation, as long as Office 2007 is installed

4) Windows 7 and Office 2010
a. Upload multiple documents will always work in this situation, as long as Office 2010 is installed
i. Windows 7 ships with .NET 3.5 pre-installed, so you should never run into this issue

Answer (score -1):

I believe its an issue with the browser version or the filename length is to large.

Comment: Can you cite any sources for that?